# STM32L0 Freeze on setting NVIC/GPIO

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, mbed

I'm working with an STM32L073RZ CPU running MbedOS 5.11.2. Eventually I aim to get this working in a very low-power mode (`STOP` mode) that will be awoken with either an RTC interrupt or an interrupt from a peripheral device on pin `PA_0` (`WAKEUP_PIN_1`). At the moment I am simply attempting to setup `PA_0` as an interrupt using the STM32 `HAL` API. Please see my code below:

```
#include "mbed.h"

#define LOG(...) pc.printf(__VA_ARGS__); pc.printf("\r\n");

DigitalOut  led(LED1);
Serial      pc(USBTX, USBRX);

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    led = !led;
}

int main()
{
    pc.baud(9600);
    led = 1;

    // GPIO SETUP
    LOG("Enabling GPIO port A clock");
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    LOG("Initialising PA_0");
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    // NVIC SETUP
    LOG("Setting IRQ Priority");
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0, 1); // Priorities can be 0, 1, 2, 3 with lowest being highest prio
    LOG("Enabling IRQ");
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

    LOG("Going into STOP mode");
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFE);
}
```

As you can see, the code is broken into two sections: GPIO setup and NVIC setup. My issue is as follows:

If I perform GPIO setup before NVIC setup then the program seems to hang on `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority()`, however, if I perform NVIC setup before GPIO setup then the code seems to hang on `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ()`.

I am completely stumped as to what is causing this. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the program "hangs"? The processor doesn't just stop executing. Does it end up on an IRQ Handler? Or does it hard fault? Or what? Usually the default IRQ Handlers supplied by the start up code are just an empty infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this manually. As long as you run Mbed OS in tickless mode (set `MBED_TICKLESS=1` macro in your mbed_app.json) the MCU will automatically enter stop mode whenever all threads are idle. If you want to wake up you can either use an `InterruptIn` on the pin or use a `LowPowerTicker`.

If you're looking for the absolute lowest power modes, you can use the standby feature (without RAM retention) for which there's a library here: [stm32-standby-rtc-wakeup](https://github.com/janjongboom/stm32-standby-rtc-wakeup).

Comment: Thanks for this information, I was completely unaware!